# On Path Finding: a detailed description for a layman of the D* algorithm

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, d-star

The large network (of small world graph type) I wish to deal with is dynamic in nature, new nodes are added and subtracted frequently. Presumably using D* over A* would be a better way to detect paths in this dynamic environment?

How solid is D*? has it had any real world experience? like a cryptographic algorithm - is  D* hardened by lots of peer review and testing? Would you use D* for this problem?

Comment: but lets hear a detailed explanation for the layman

Comment: I think the closest you are going to get is going to be to read the pseudo-code and the accompanying explanation in the original whitepaper for D* that I linked to.  It is in pretty "layman" terms.. but you won't be able to understand D* without ~some~ graph theory background.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As I understand, the first time you run D* it finds the same path as A* with nearly the same runtime.  However, when a node changes it's edge value or nodes are added A* recomputes ALL of the path while D* simply recomputes the inconsistent nodes the second time around rather than the whole thing.

Anthony Stentz's D* algorithm (original whitepaper [here](http://www.frc.ri.cmu.edu/~axs/doc/icra94.pdf)) has largely been deprecated by derivatives of his work.  D* Lite and LPA* are the most commonly found and are much easier to code/implement.

As far as real world experience,  Joseph Carsten and Art Rankin from NASA's Jet Propulsion Laboratory installed a version of Field D* using elements of D* Lite on the mars rovers "Spirit" and "Opportunity" (slideshow of rovers using D* [here](http://www.ceng.metu.edu.tr/~erogul/ceng585/13_DEC_2007_Presentation/d-star-hidden-slides-deleted.ppt)).  In Feburary 2007 it was used to fully navigate the mars rover autonomously.

[alt text http://asm.arc.nasa.gov/Gallery/images/generic/rover.jpg](http://asm.arc.nasa.gov/Gallery/images/generic/rover.jpg)

Apparently D* is really useful in the robotics domain because the robots on-board sensors are constantly re-evaluating edge values.  That would make it pretty "battle tested" in my own opinion.

Similarly, I found another [whitepaper](http://www.stes.fi/scai2006/proceedings/176-182.pdf) that mentions the use of the D* Lite algorithm in Mobile Gaming.

I'll end this answer by stating that I've never implemented D* before, only A*.  Because of the significant increase in complexity I would say that D* (or D* Lite) should only be used in cases where there is a significant and frequent changes in the graph.  You described your situation as being similar to that so I would say definately go for D* Lite.  If NASA uses it you could safely bet it has been thoroughly investigated.

Comment: You said that D* should be used when there is a frequent change in the graph. Does this means that D* shouldn't be used if the graph doesn't change at all??

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented both D* and A* algorithm. So, I advice you that, if your map has no dynamic obstacles, you should implement A*. Else, implement D*. For the main reason is:
At the first search, D* calculates all nodes in the map, then shows you  the shortest path, while A* only calculates a limited area around goal and start points in the map. So, it is much faster than D*.
In dynamic environment, D* is faster and more efficient than A*. Because on the way robot goes, if it detects a new obstacle, it only updates a few nodes around the unexpected obstacle. While, A* will calculates again all things.